# Why my Favicon doesn't appear on Google Search Results

Tags: html, image, styles, favicon, meta

I'm stuck for a while on my Favicon issue. Somehow my Favicon does appear on the address bar but doesn't appear on google search results even all files are in the root folder. Here the code I'm using for:

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="/apple-touch-icon.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="/favicon-32x32.png">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="/favicon-16x16.png">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
<link rel="manifest" href="/site.webmanifest">
<link rel="mask-icon" href="/safari-pinned-tab.svg" color="#5bbad5">
<meta name="msapplication-TileColor" content="#da532c">
```

[This Is The Root Folder Where The Favicon File Is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wh5nU.png)

Answer (score 0):

Read following [google webmaster article](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/9290858) on how to add icons to the search results. 
When setup correct it will be displayed after your site is crawled by google.

However i believe google is still experimenting after receiving a huge backlash from users claiming the UI was now to clutterd...

Comment: Thanks for the answer, according to the guidelines on google webmaster article  I have done everything correctly. Maybe I have to wait for google crawling my icon...